# Input number, then display amount of words per line

Tags: c#

Afternoon, trying to learn how to program in C#.  My question is:  I have 500 words of text.  Part of the task is to ask the user to input a number, say 25, then have the program show 25 words per line.  My book is vague on how to do this.  I have completed the rest of the task, but stuck in this one area.  I am sure that I am missing something simple.
**Pseudocode:
Prompt user to enter number 1-50
Input number (exp: 25)
Display amount of text that corresponds to number inputted (25 words display, next line show 25 words, etc.)**

Yes, this is a homework question.
Yes, I have asked my instructor and waiting for a response.
A coworker suggested that I try this site.
Any help is appreciated.  Book I am using is "Visual C#, How to Program."

Comment: Thanks for letting us know its a homework question. As the teacher will likely ask, what have you tried? Where have you failed? Maybe you are extremely close to the correct answer. What pseudo-code have you tried?

Comment: You should be able to [split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) the original text and then [join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0(v=vs.110).aspx) groups of 25 individual elements (i.e. words).

Comment: @Esaith  This is what I have tried  String[] words = myParagraph.Split(' ');
   string[] query = myParagraph.Split(' ').Take(228).ToArray();
   myParagraph = String.Join(" ", query);

   string[] sentences = myParagraph.Split(new char[] { '.' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
   foreach (string sentence in sentences)
   {
    Console.WriteLine(sentence.Split(' ').Length + " words in sentence *" + sentence + "*");
   }

   if (sentence >= 18)
    Console.WriteLine("Press C to continue.");
   else
    Console.WriteLine("Press Q to quit.");

Comment: When I run the code, it displays how many words are per line.  I think I am halfway there, just not sure where to go from here.

Comment: @TonyGutierrez see my answer, it should be what you are looking for. It looks like what you have already tried won't work for all cases as there are some hard coded numbers.

Answer (score 0):

First you will need to read in how many words per line to write out. This is very straightforward. As Jeeped pointed out, you will need to split the text into a set of words and then print out just 25 words per line.

```
Console.Write("Enter number of words per line: ");
int wordsPerLine = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

string source = @""; // fill in your text here
string[] words = source.Split(' ');

for (int i = 0; i < words.Length; i++) {
    if (i % wordsPerLine == 0) {
        Console.WriteLine();
    }

    Console.Write(words[i]);
    Console.Write(" ");
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

Basically this is just reading through the split array of words and when it has gone through the input number of words then it puts down a new line and keeps printing out the results.

Note that you should do some error handling to make sure an integer is actually the input.